# How do I show $1-\frac{X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{D}Y$ with $X_n\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ and $Y$ having a degenerate distribution in $1-p$?

Tags: probability

Towards an application of Lévy-Cramér, I obtain
$$\varphi_{1-X_n/n}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{it(1-\frac{X_n}{n})})=e^{it}\varphi_{X_n}(-t/n)=e^{it}(1-p+pe^{-it/n})^n$$
from the characteristic function of the binomial distribution. Taking the limit,
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\varphi_{1-X_n/n}(t)=e^{it}\lim_{n\to+\infty}(1-p+pe^{-it/n})^n.$$
I am struggling to show equality of this limit with $\varphi_{Y}(t)=e^{i(1-p)t}$ (which would complete the exercise) and would appreciate a hint. Thanks for considering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log$ is the principal logarithm, it is analytic at $1$ and we may inspect its Taylor series. For $t$ fixed and $n$ large, $\log(1-p+pe^{-it/n})=\log(1+p(e^{-it/n}-1))=p(e^{-it/n}-1)-\frac{1}{2}p^2(e^{-it/n}-1)^2+\cdots$

Observe $e^{-it/n}-1=-it/n+\cdots\in O(1/n)$. So, $\log(1-p+pe^{-it/n})=-pit/n+O(1/n^2)=-pit/n+o(1/n)$ can be deduced.

In particular, $n\log(1-p+pe^{-it/n})=-pit+o(1)\to-pit$; therefore $(1-p+pe^{-it/n})^n\to e^{-pit}$, which gives what you need.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli$(0,1;p)$ random variables. The law of large numbers implies that $\frac{X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}p$ almost surely. It follows that $1-\frac{X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1-p$ almost surely, and this in distribution, i.e. $1-\frac{X_n}{n}\Longrightarrow\delta_{1-p}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Just a caveat, $X_n$ is equal in distribution to the sum of $n$ i.i.d. $\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ r.v.'s I don't think it will be equal to it a.s. unless some extra hypotheses are assumed, so $1 - \frac{X_n}{n}$ converges to $1-p$ in distribution but maybe not a.s.

Comment: @WilliamM. Sure, in distribution, $X_n$ is the sum of $n$ $\operatorname{Be}(0,1;p)$ random variables. But one might aw well start with i.d.d Bernoulli random variables $(B_n)$ and set $X_n=B_1+\ldots+ B_n$ ( a realization of the problem).

Comment: That is a common technique, and it is probably the heart of probability: replace a distribution (difficult object) by a representation in terms of i.i.d. r.v.'s which then behave like real numbers. Thus, one reduces a functional analysis problem into a calculus one.